# How to decorate interfaces bound to more than one concrete type with Ninject

Tags: ninject, decorator

So, I have a message bus that instantiates message handlers through Ninject. I'd like to decorate my handlers with cross cutting concerns such as logging, transaction management, etc.

I setup my bindings like so:

```cs
kernel.Bind<IMessageHandler<int>>().To<IntHandlerOne>()
    .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(HandlerDecorator<>));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IMessageHandler<>)).To(typeof(HandlerDecorator<>));
```

Which works fantastically whenever I have a single handler of a specific message type. However, when I have more than one handler defined:

```cs
kernel.Bind<IMessageHandler<int>>().To<IntHandlerOne>()
    .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(HandlerDecorator<>));
kernel.Bind<IMessageHandler<int>>().To<IntHandlerTwo>()
    .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(HandlerDecorator<>));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IMessageHandler<>)).To(typeof(HandlerDecorator<>));
```

Ninject will find and inject the decorator to the message bus, and then attempt unsuccessfully to inject both handlers into the decorator constructor.

```cs
public HandlerDecorator(IMessageHandler<T> handler)
```

You may be thinking, why don't I just modify my decorator to accept the list of handlers? I thought about this, but that defeats the purpose of the handler. I want to be able to easily chain multiple decorators together transparently. Each instance of `IMessageHandler<T>` should get an entirely new chain of handlers.

I've published [an example](https://github.com/kmcginnes/POC.NinjectMessageHandlerDecoration) test library on GitHub that should illustrate what I'm talking about here.

Is there any way to do this in Ninject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
kernel.Bind<IMessageHandler<int>>().To<IntHandlerOne>().WhenParentNamed("One");
kernel.Bind<IMessageHandler<int>>().To<IntHandlerTwo>().WhenParentNamed("Two");
kernel.Bind(typeof(IMessageHandler<>)).To(typeof(HandlerDecorator<>)).Named("One");
kernel.Bind(typeof(IMessageHandler<>)).To(typeof(HandlerDecorator<>)).Named("Two");
```

Also be aware that most of the Bus Frameworks have some way to do decorations for message handlers. May have a look there first.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap those handlers in a [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

```cs
public class CompositeMessageHandler<T> : IMessageHandler<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IMessageHandler<T>> handlers;

    CompositeMessageHandler(IEnumerable<IMessageHandler<T>> handlers)
    {
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    public void Handle(T message)
    {
        foreach (var handler in this.handlers)
        {
            handler.Handle(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This composite can again be injected into your decorator. Or perhaps you should do it the other way around: Wrap each handler with a decorator and wrap those into the composite.

I'm not sure how to register this with Ninject though.

Comment: This is what I was hinting at towards the bottom of my question. The problem with this is when I have multiple decorators. For example I want to wrap all handlers with a transaction decorator per handler AND a logging decorator per handler. If I use the composite then I can only choose one of those decorators to be a composite. The other decorator would end up decorating the decorator, and would therefore only execute once for all handlers rather than once per handler.