# How to decorate named bindings in Ninject

Tags: c#, polymorphism, ninject, decorator, ioc-container

I have an interface that has multiple implementations.  These implementations are set up via named bindings:

```
Bind<IService>().To<FirstService>().Named("First");
Bind<IService>().To<SecondService>().Named("Second");
Bind<IService>().To<ThirdService>().Named("Third");
```

However, each of these services need to be decorated as well:

```
Bind<IService>().To<FirstService>().WhenInjectedInto<FirstDecorator>();
Bind<IService>().To<FirstDecorator>().WhenInjectedInto<SecondDecorator>();
Bind<IService>().To<SecondDecorator>();
```

I know that there is the `WhenParentNamed` and `WhenAnyAncestorNamed` contextual binding, but they seem to be mutually exclusive with the `WhenInjectedInto`.  How can I set up Ninject so that it will honor both the decoration and the named bindings?  I have a `Provider` scheme set up that does work, but I wanted to see if there was a way to do this natively in Ninject, without the custom providers.

```
Bind<IService>().ToProvider(new ServiceProvider("First")).Named("First");
Bind<IService>().ToProvider(new ServiceProvider("Second")).Named("Second");
Bind<IService>().ToProvider(new ServiceProvider("Third")).Named("Third");
```

---

```
class ServiceProvider : Provider<IService>
{
    private readonly string name;

    public ServiceProvider(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected override CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var service = GetService(name);

        var otherDependency = context.Kernel.Get<OtherDependency>();
        service = new FirstDecorator(service, otherDependency);

        service = new SecondDecorator(service);

        return service;
    }

    private IService GetService(string name, IContext context)
    {
        switch(name)
        {
            case "First": return context.Kernel.Get<FirstService>();
            case "Second": return context.Kernel.Get<SecondService>();
            case "Third": return context.Kernel.Get<ThirdService>();
            default: throw new ArugmentException($"No binding for {name}");
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278958/how-to-decorate-interfaces-bound-to-more-than-one-concrete-type-with-ninject), but since it does not deal with named bindings, it does not seem applicable.

Ideally, it would be something like this:

```
Bind<IService>().To<FirstService>().WhenInjectedInto<FirstDecorator>().Named("First");
Bind<IService>().To<SecondService>().WhenInjectedInto<FirstDecorator>().Named("Second");
Bind<IService>().To<ThirdService>().WhenInjectedInto<FirstDecorator>().Named("Third");
Bind<IService>().To<FirstDecorator>().WhenInjectedInto<SecondDecorator>();
Bind<IService>().To<SecondDecorator>();
```

**Update**: Here is how I expect to call for one of these decorated services:

```
kernel.Get<IService>("First");
```

or

```
[Inject, Named("First")]
public IService Service {get; set;}
```

The last is for some automated integration tests.

**Update 2**: I have tried this, and it does not work (complains of duplicate bindings, presumably because it is not honoring the names on the concrete implementation bindings)

```
Bind<IService>().To<FirstService>().WhenInjectedInto<FirstDecorator>().Named("First");
Bind<IService>().To<SecondService>().WhenInjectedInto<FirstDecorator>().Named("Second");
Bind<IService>().To<ThirdService>().WhenInjectedInto<FirstDecorator>().Named("Third");
Bind<IService>().To<FirstDecorator>().WhenInjectedInto<SecondDecorator>().Named("First");
Bind<IService>().To<FirstDecorator>().WhenInjectedInto<SecondDecorator>().Named("Second");
Bind<IService>().To<FirstDecorator>().WhenInjectedInto<SecondDecorator>().Named("Third");
Bind<IService>().To<SecondDecorator>().Named("First");
Bind<IService>().To<SecondDecorator>().Named("Second");
Bind<IService>().To<SecondDecorator>().Named("Third");
```

**Update 3:** Doing the following ALMOST works:

```
Bind<IService>().To<FirstService>().WhenAnyAncestorNamed("First");
Bind<IService>().To<SecondService>().WhenAnyAncestorNamed("Second");
Bind<IService>().To<ThirdService>().WhenAnyAncestorNamed("Third");

Bind<IService>().To<FirstDecorator>().WhenInjectedInto<SecondDecorator>().Named("First");

Bind(typeof(IService)).To(typeof(SecondDecorator)).Named("First");
Bind(typeof(IService)).To(typeof(SecondDecorator)).Named("Second");
Bind(typeof(IService)).To(typeof(SecondDecorator)).Named("Third");
```

The problem is that when it tries to build the `SecondDecorator`, there are two matching bindings: one to the concrete implementation (if named "First", then `FirstService`), and one to the `FirstDecorator`.

Comment: How do you expect to resolve the service? By invoking `Get<IService>("First")`?

Comment: Correct.  I'll update the question with that information

Answer (score 0):

I ended up hand-rolling my own decoration method:

```
public override void Load()
{
    var decorators = new[]
    {
        typeof(FirstDecorator),
        typeof(SecondDecorator)
    };

    Decorate<IService, FirstService>("First", decorators);
    Decorate<IService, SecondService>("Second", decorators);
    Decorate<IService, ThirdService>("Third", decorators);
}

private void Decorate<S, T>(string name, params Type[] decorators)
    where T : S
{
    var allImplementations = new[] { typeof(T) }.Union(decorators);

    foreach (var implementation in allImplementations)
    {
        Bind<S>().To(implementation).When(r => Need(implementation, r, name, allImplementations));
    }

    Bind<S>().To(allImplementations.Last()).Named(name);
}

private bool Need(Type implementation, IRequest request, string name, IEnumerable<Type> implementations)
{
    var implementationsList = implementations.ToList();
    var depth = implementationsList.Count - implementationsList.IndexOf(implementation);

    return request.Depth == depth && request.ActiveBindings.Any(b => b.Metadata.Name == name);
}
```

I will be looking to see if I can refactor this into a `When`-type clause and submit as a pull request to Ninject

**UPDATE**

Refactored this into a better version using a custom When extension:

```
public static class WhenExtensions
{
    public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenInjectedInto<T>(
        this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> syntax, Type parentType, string name)
    {
        var condition = ComputeMatchCondition<T>(syntax, parentType);
        return syntax.When(request => condition(request)
            && request.ActiveBindings.Any(b => b.Metadata.Name == name));
    }

    private static Func<IRequest, bool> ComputeMatchCondition<T>(
        IBindingWhenSyntax<T> syntax, Type parentType)
    {
        syntax.WhenInjectedInto(parentType);
        return syntax.BindingConfiguration.Condition;
    }
}
```

Then called like this:

```
    public override void Load()
    {
        var decorators = new[]
        {
            typeof(FirstDecorator),
            typeof(SecondDecorator),
        };

        NameAndDecorate<IService, FirstService>("First", decorators);
        NameAndDecorate<IService, SecondService>("Second", decorators);
        NameAndDecorate<IService, ThirdService>("Third", decorators);
    }

    private void NameAndDecorate<S, T>(string name, params Type[] decorators)
        where T : S
    {
        Bind<S>().To(decorators[0]).Named(name);

        for (var i = 1; i < decorators.Length; i++)
        {
            Bind<S>().To(decorators[i]).WhenInjectedInto(decorators[i - 1], name);
        }

        Bind<S>().To<T>().WhenInjectedInto(decorators.Last(), name);
    }
}
```

This works much better, as trying to rely on Depth of the invocation produced strange results where, on occasion, some decorators would be omitted.

Important to note that the order of the decorators does influence how they are stacked - first in the list is "top", and each decorator following is inside.  For most decorators, this won't be an issue, but if you want to order your decorators (say, by putting proxies first), then you can.